# Process Builder criteria using parent object fields doesn't validate

Tags: process-builder

I'm using Process Builder as in SFDC's Spring '15 release, where it's not beta anymore but appears to be the final version they're gonna roll out soon.

The Process I'm having an issue with runs on a (child) object and needs to run if certain fields on its parent object record have certain values. And it just doesn't work: according to the debug logs the Process gets called but the decision returns false (no matter what I enter on the record) which makes the Process stop. The logs don't give away a lot of information but it seems like the values of the parent object record don't even get passed to the Process. Did anyone else run into this issue and knows how to solve this?

What makes it really confusing for me is that I built pretty much identical Processes on other objects before and they run just fine.

I appreciate any help! Thanks :)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have a similar problem here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/73361/process-builder-field-update-action-not-executing

In my case it looks like it's evaluating to true in the debug log, but the action still isn't being executed.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Any solution on this.