# Process Builder field update action not executing

Tags: process-builder

I just built a process in Process Builder that isn't behaving as expected.  It's firing on a child object in a master-detail, and the criteria is a formula involving fields on both the child and the parent object.  The action is a field update on the parent obj (picklist field).

When I test it the field update does not occur.

Looking in debug log, though, it looks like the criteria is evaluating to true.  Any idea why the action wouldn't be happening, in that case?

Debug log:

`33.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
17:19:05.053 (53998607)|EXECUTION_STARTED
17:19:05.054 (54020668)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:01IJ0000000AUeF
17:19:05.071 (71959972)|WF_RULE_EVAL_BEGIN|Workflow
17:19:05.071 (71982540)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Work Party Report: WPR-1 a2KJ0000000Y6kn]|VMS_WP_Status_to_Completed_when_Report_Submitted301J00000000hGW|01QJ00000001TA2|ON_ALL_CHANGES|0
17:19:05.072 (72085557)|WF_FORMULA|Formula:ENCODED:[treatNullAsNull]true|Values:
17:19:05.072 (72092232)|WF_CRITERIA_END|true
17:19:05.072 (72750427)|WF_CRITERIA_BEGIN|[Work Party Report: WPR-1 a2KJ0000000Y6kn]|VMS: Set Travel Time on Work Party|01QJ00000001Pkk|ON_ALL_CHANGES|0
17:19:05.073 (73967309)|WF_FORMULA|Formula:ENCODED:[treatNullAsNull]ISCHANGED( {!ID:00NJ0000001iTRS} )|Values:Total_Admin_Prep_Travel_Hours__c=10
17:19:05.073 (73973235)|WF_CRITERIA_END|false
17:19:05.073 (73988928)|WF_SPOOL_ACTION_BEGIN|Workflow
17:19:05.074 (74008795)|WF_ACTION| Flow Trigger: 1;
17:19:05.074 (74012095)|WF_RULE_EVAL_END
17:19:05.074 (74497316)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_BEGIN|09LJ000000001bm
17:19:05.076 (76067585)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00DJ0000003OYAA|300J000000007oL|301J00000000hGW
17:19:05.077 (77512729)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_END|84945228a7ca7446766464e663f914cedd0822a-74d8|VMS: WP Status to Completed when Report Submitted
17:19:05.078 (78440250)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_BEGIN|1
17:19:05.079 (79948413)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|84945228a7ca7446766464e663f914cedd0822a-74d8|VMS: WP Status to Completed when Report Submitted
17:19:05.081 (81373905)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEW_END|84945228a7ca7446766464e663f914cedd0822a-74d8|VMS: WP Status to Completed when Report Submitted
17:19:05.081 (81394726)|FLOW_START_INTERVIEWS_END|1
17:19:05.083 (83107587)|WF_FLOW_ACTION_END|09LJ000000001bm
17:19:05.083 (83169103)|WF_ACTIONS_END| Flow Trigger: 1;
17:19:05.083 (83173714)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:01IJ0000000AUeF
17:19:05.084 (84670704)|EXECUTION_FINISHED`

Comment: Huh.  I thought that the `WF_CRITERIA_END|true` in the log meant the process criteria was met.  But I tried it again and put in something that patently doesn't meet the criteria, but I still see `WF_CRITERIA_END|true` in the debug log for this process.  Huh?